# Formulario dinamico en angular 2 ¿se puede realizar?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

me gustaria preguntarle si sabeis si es posible en la tecnologia angular 2, hacer un formulario, que algunos compos validen en funcion de otro capmo como por ejemplo un checkbox que al ser true su valor activa la validacion de otros dos inputs.

Grácias

Comment: El Problema principal es que no puedo quitar la validacion de los "campos extras" en funcion del valor del checkbox, Utilizo reactive controls de angular forms Grácias pro su atencion

Answer (score 1):

si se puede, consulta esta documentación oficial:

[Form validation in Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html)

Podrías lanzar una función en la directiva ngModelChange que cambie la variable que necesitas y en la condición de la validación la consultas para actuar de una forma u otra.

Ya nos cuentas.
Saludos.

Comment: Ya lo ley y continuo tiniendo el problema, a lo mejor soy yo que no se ver la respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible, depende de que es lo que necesitas en tu formulario, puedes usar ng-change para checkbox y ng-show o ng-if en los input.
Este podría ser el código del checkbox y los input...

```
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="activo" ng-change="activar()">
        <input type="text" ng-show="activarInput" name="input1">
        <input type="text" ng-show="activarInput" name="input2">
```

aqui puedes definir un valor inicial del checkbox, por default vamos a dejarlo en false, en el controlador tendríamos lo siguiente.

```
        var app = angular.module("app", [])
        app.controller("appCtrl", function(){
             $scope.activo = false;
             //lo sigiente activa o desactiva los input
             //suponiendo que se activen los dos al mismo tiempo
             $scope.activarInput = false;
             $scope.activar = function(){
                   $scope.activo = true;
                   $scope.activarInput = true;
             }
        });
```

Espero que esto sea lo que necesitas, saludos.

Comment: El problema no es mostrar o no el campo, como has dicho la solucion seria sencilla con los controles adequados, el problema es su validacion, en cuanto añado el valdiador custom con un parametro boolean este se queda en el valor inicial i no canvia con el valor del checkbox Muchas Grácias po contestar!!

Comment: entonces lo que quieres hacer es que si un checkbox es seleccionado, se valide dos input por ejemplo validar que contengan solo texto o números? agrega código de tus avances, sería mas fácil ayudarte así.

Answer (score 1):

Pude encontrar la respuesta que necesitaba. Al final lo que encuentro, es subscribirme al evento de ngModelChange del checkbox en cuestión y con el siguiente código añado los validadores o los saco del grupo.

```
onEsRegalChanged(value: any) {
        //Posar i treure els validadors en funcio del valor del checkbox;
        if (!value) {
            this.nomDestinatari.setValidators([]);
            this.carrer.setValidators([]);
        } else {
            this.nomDestinatari.setValidators([
                Validators.required
            ]);
            this.carrer.setValidators([
                Validators.required
            ]);
        }

    }
```

Pero debe ser un FormControl necesariamente para poner validadores!